# What's the best way to sum the result of a member function for all elements in a container?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, member-functions

Let's say I have the following object:

```
struct Foo
{
    int size() { return 2; }
};
```

What's the best way (most maintainable, readable, etc.) to get the total `size` of all objects in a `vector<Foo>`?  I'll post my solution but I'm interested in better ideas.

**Update:**

So far we have:

- std::accumulate and a functor
- std::accumulate and a lambda expression
- plain ol' for-loop

Are there any other workable solutions?  Can you make something maintainable using `boost::bind` or `std::bind1st/2nd`?

Comment: `std::vector<Foo> vec; vec.size() * 2`, since we know that `Foo::size` always returns 2. :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In addition to your own suggestion, if your compiler supports C++0x lambda expressions, you can use this shorter version:

```
std::vector<Foo> vf;

// do something to populate vf


int totalSize = std::accumulate(vf.begin(),
                                vf.end(),
                                0, 
                                [](int sum, const Foo& elem){ return sum + elem.size();});
```

Comment: typo: a semicolon is missing at the end of the body of the lambda (I can't edit myself).

Answer (score 8):

Use [std::accumulate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/numeric/accumulate/) and a functor.

```
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>

struct SumSizes : public std::binary_function<int, Foo, int>
{
    int operator()(int total, const Foo& elem) const
    {
        return total + elem.size();
    }
};

std::vector<Foo> vf;

// do something to populate vf

int totalSize = std::accumulate(vf.begin(),
                                vf.end(),
                                0, 
                                SumSizes());
```

Comment: Your solution is the most idiomatic one, of course, but a dumb iterator loop might be easier in such simple cases.

Comment: +1 This would be improved by templating `SumSizes` for genericity, since all standard containers have a `size()` member function.

Comment: @Jon, I think you may have misunderstood the question.  The point was not to get the size of the container, but to sum the result of a member function of all elements.  Perhaps `size` was a poor name for such a function.

Comment: No, I understood the question, and just thought I'd make an odd point because your example happens to use the identifier `size()`. If made generic, `SumSizes` would sum the individual sizes of each element of a container of containers (or sequences, for example `std::string`). Incidentally. :P

Answer (score 7):

I find Boost iterators elegants, although they can be a bit verbose (range-based algorithms would make this better). In this case [transform iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) can do the job:

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
//...

int totalSize = std::accumulate(
    boost::make_transform_iterator(vf.begin(), std::mem_fn(&Foo::size)),
    boost::make_transform_iterator(vf.end(), std::mem_fn(&Foo::size)),0);
```

Edit: replaced "`boost::bind(&Foo::size,_1)`" by "`std::mem_fn(&Foo::size)`"

Edit: I just found that the Boost.Range library has been updated to introduce range algorithms! Here is a new version of the same solution:

```
#include <boost/range/distance.hpp> // numeric.hpp needs it (a bug?)
#include <boost/range/numeric.hpp> // accumulate
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp> // transformed
//...
int totalSize = boost::accumulate(
    vf | boost::adaptors::transformed(std::mem_fn(Foo::size)), 0);
```

Note: the performances are approximately the same (see my comment): internally, `transformed` uses `transorm_iterator`.

Comment: I did timings comparing this solution and the direct one, and unfortunately this one is slower (I found a factor between 2 and 5). However this may not be a concern.

Comment: I think this is the best answer.  The problem is **what** to accumulate, which is addressed by a custom iterator, not **how** to accumulate, which is addressed by using a functor.  The default accumulation behaviour (plus) _is_ what you want.  Consider extending this problem to the inner product: the transformed iterator is reusable whereas the functor is not. A new functor for every algorithm would be required simply to redefine the default behaviour in terms of member size().

Answer (score 6):

using C++11 (and beyond) range-based for loop

```
std::vector<Foo> vFoo;
// populate vFoo with some values...
int totalSize = 0;
for (const auto& element: vFoo) {
    totalSize += element.size();
}
```

Comment: Like this solution. I find std::accumulate requires extra brain power: need to know the type of the container (Foo). Must not screw up the type of the initial value. Way longer to type, thus to read.  Need to use cbegin/cend() and const on the argument of the lambda to ensure constness.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the down-to-earth solution:

```
typedef std::vector<Foo> FooVector;
FooVector vf;
int totalSize = 0;
for (FooVector::const_iterator it = vf.begin(); it != vf.end(); ++it) {
  totalSize += it->size();
}
```