# C++ looping through a vector of structure

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

say I have

```
 struct S {
    double A;
    double B;
    double C;
  };
```

and

```
   std::vector<S> vecS(10);
```

I am trying to write a generic function `void F(std::vector<S> vecS,structure S.x)` such that the following computation can happen

```
 F(std::vector<S> vecS, structure S.x) {
        for(i=1;i<10;i++)
          vecS[0].x += vecS[i].x;  
       // note the structure does not have memeber "x"
       // I want to give that as a generic input to access A,B or C
  }
```

The above code is not correct code, but I am just trying to demonstrate what I am trying to compute.

What I am trying to compute is loop over the vector of structs for a specific element. Is this possible in a simple nice way? Can someone please give me some pointers how to access a member of a structure in a generic way (maybe that is what I need to write this function).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a bit like http://stackoverflow.com/a/3205057/667798 - I'd suggest doing an `accumulate` over the vector using a lambda expression that extracts the member variable you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a pointer to member:

```
void F( std::vector<S> &vecS, double S::*ptr )
{
    for(i=1;i<10;i++)
       vecS[0].*ptr += vecS[i].*ptr;  
}

// now call for A
F( vec, &S::A );
```

If you need it to work with different types, not only `double` as in this case, use template.

PS I did not notice first, but you have to pass vector as reference, as you modifying element in it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not generic in the sense that you have a vector hardcoded, but let's ignore that for a second.

What you want is a pointer-to-member:

```
template <typename T, typename M>
F(std::vector<S> vecS, M T::* member) {
        for(i=1;i<10;i++)
          vecS[0].*member += vecS[i].*member;  
}
```

Call as `F(vec, &myClass::A)`

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is called a pointer to member. You can't use the exact syntax as you have written, and pointer to member syntax is rather ugly and not commonly used. But here's the basics.

```
double S::*x = &S::A;
vecS[0]->*x += vecS[i]->*x
```

See the following for more details:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_pointer-to-member_access_operators
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer

Also, unrelated to your question, but you need to declare the type of your loop variable `i`. Currently, it is undefined.